# Stop WordPress from reserving slugs for media items?

Tags: permalinks, attachments, media, slug

I am experiencing some odd behavior, that apparently happens "out of the box" with WordPress.

If I upload a file through the media manager called: `services.jpg;` then go try to create a page with the permalink `http://example.com/services/;` The slug `services-2` is given instead, because the attachment is already using that slug.

Visiting `http://example.com/services/` loads the attachment page.

I have not enabled any plugins or added anything into functions.php to modify the rewrites for attachments.

Has anyone run into this before? Know where to start to disable this functionality?

Comment: This is standard functionality from WordPress Core, posts cannot have the same slugs, regardless of post type ( attachments are posts too, of type `attachment`, as are pages which are of type `page` ). This is to prevent clashes. There are some bits of code that might help, but I'm unfamiliar with the specifics. Also, this is something that will eventually be fixed in Core, or at least have some sort of solution, Eitherway the problem is ambiguity, what if you have a post type `services` a page called `services` and a normal post, and you set your permalinks to only have the name?

Comment: Fixing it for everybody is a non trivial problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the response everyone. I played around with macemmek's solution and I think it led me to an even better solution:

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_attachment_slug', '__return_true' );
```

That is all that is needed. This will automatically 'skip' the default assigned slug on any attachment. So an attachment that might normally get the slug "services" will now get the slug "services-2".

Comment: Perfect and elegant for a conscious admin, so +1. However, it is possible that some user trashes "services" blog post and creates another one which will get "services-2" slug and we have 2 items slugged "services-2". My clients do this always. ;)

Comment: Actually based on the code I am seeing, WP would attempt to give out services-2, however if it is taken like in your example, it will then try -3, -4, -5, etc until it finds a unique slug.

Comment: I've tried this. I have two "services-2" posts in the database, really.

Comment: Very strange, I can't reproduce that behavior you are seeing. I just tested it out on WordPress 4.1.1. If services-2 slug already exists, the new attachment gets the slug services-3. Which lines up with the expected behavior that I am seeing in the do while function here in the codebase: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3688

If you are able to reproduce the steps that led to a duplicate slug being produced, we could submit a ticket to the WordPress core bug tracker.

Comment: I did a slighty different thing: I had an attachment-type post "services-2" and then I've changed a slug of "services" blog post to "services-2" and it has been stored in DB.

Comment: When I do what you mentioned, the services blog post gets the slug services-2-2

Comment: I've reproduced it again (WP 4.1.1). 1) Added your line to functions.php; 2) Uploaded media image which gets in my case "samsung-2" post_name; 3) Added a blog post titled "Samsung" so it gets "samsung" post name. 4) Added another blog post titled "Samsung" and it gets... "samsung-2" post_name.  I don't know, why we have different results, it's quite interesting. :)

Comment: I haven't looked at the latest code but I think the issue is in the handling of post types in wp_unique_post_slug().  The SQL query is only searching within the same post-type so it will not check for a collision with attachments.

Answer (score 4):

You may hook wp_unique_post_slug() and append some string to the original slug if the post is an attachment type. The original slug based on post title will remain free.

UPDATED after Rachel Baker's comment: original slug suffix is some random string. It does not guarantee uniqueness but may be enough for simple use cases.

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'wpse17916_unique_post_slug', 10, 6 );
function wpse17916_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
  if ( 'attachment' == $post_type )
    $slug = $original_slug . uniqid( '-' );
  return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea

Comment: The wp_unique_post_slug filter is a great solution, however it can also cause issues if not used carefully.  There would still need to be a condition added that checks if the $original_slug variable is unique among the attachment posts to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Right. I've improved the answer with uniqid() suffix. I'm aware that full and bulletproof solution should check uniqueness in DB.

Comment: This is a good solution, although looking through the wp_unique_post_slug() function I think I found an even cleaner solution to this problem. See my answer for details.

Comment: You're right but then the uniqueness can be broken from another side: blog post. (See my comment)

Answer (score 1):

Tom's comment is correct, in that this is normal behaviour and there is not much you can do to stop it.

But you can change slugs after things are uploaded/created. While you shouldn't do this if the links are known/publicised/listed on search engines, if you're just trying to fix this problem occasionally after an upload then you can edit the slug of the attachment (to be something like `services-attachment`), and then edit the slug of the page to be `services`.

To do this, go to Media, click Edit under the attachment you want to edit (or if on grid view, click the attachment then click Edit more details), then at the top you'll see the permalink.. clicking Edit here will let you change the slug.

Then repeat the same process for the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do here is use a redirect to prevent people from seeing the media items. It's a good fit with the other solutions presented here. Prepend something to the media item slugs, the write a redirect to 'get rid' of the media pages.