# Attachment pages stealing page slugs

Tags: pages, attachments, slug

I'm working on remaking a big website with its upload folder already full of many gigabits of images. I just noticed a problem I never noticed with WordPress before: it seems to create attachment pages based on the name of the images, which means that it "steals" most of the page slugs I want to use.

For example, let's say I have an image named `about.jpg` in my upload folder. The URL `mysite.com/about` will be created and automatically redirect to that image. Now, if I want to create a regular page named *About*, the URL doesn't have the priority on the attachment and will be forced be called `mysite.com/about-2`.

It's quite frustrating to not have clean URLs, and I haven't found much on the web about it, which is strange. It tried the filter mentioned [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179162/stop-wordpress-from-reserving-slugs-for-media-items) but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: The filter would probably only work if you set it up before importing the images. If your images are already imported then I guess you either want some behaviour to spot if an image already has a slug on page save and rename it out of the way, or just e.g. run some SQL to change all the slugs where post_type = 'attachment'? Is that something you could try, after you've taken a database backup?

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) This is indeed what I ended up doing. I just changed the slugs that I needed in the database, and they became available.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a workaround if someone has the same problem:

In the database, you can search for the attachment page that's causing problem, you'll find it in `wp_posts` by searching for its `post_name` (which is the slug you want). Then just rename that post_name (in `about-img` for example). It isn't a fix but it will make the desired slug available for your page's URL.